# Why does choice.com creates an infinite loop in a Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, batch-choice

Yesterday, I have downloaded the `choice.com` command from this [FTP link](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/Services/TechNet/Windows/msdos/RESKIT/SUPPDISK/CHOICE.COM) to use it on Windows XP. From command line it works correctly, as you can see in this example:

> C:\DOCUME~1\Rodolfo>choice /c:12345 "Choose the output:"
>   Choose the output:[1,2,3,4,5]? 5
>   
> C:\DOCUME~1\Rodolfo>echo %ERRORLEVEL% 
>   5

I try to use it also into a batch file but, although the syntax seems to be correct, it creates an infinite loop, as shown in the following quotation:

> Press any key to continue...
> Press any key to continue...
> Press any key to continue..

Here are the instructions inside the Batch file:

> @echo off
> pause
> choice /c:12345 "Choose your output:"
> if %ERRORLEVEL%
>   EQU 1 echo You have chosen 1
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 echo You have
>   chosen 2
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 3 echo You have chosen 3
> if %ERRORLEVEL%
>   EQU 4 echo You have chosen 4
> if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 5 echo You have
>   chosen 5
> pause

So, why does this command seem to not work correctly in Batch files although it works fine from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call your batch file `choice` as it executes itself in a loop.

Comment: Damn, I did. Hardest to find errors in scripting or programming are always the most stupid ones.